# How can I get the datatype of an array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, types

I am making a sort of statistical software that firstly needs to 'detect' the datatype of an array.

Firstly, X[,] is an array of **sometype**, can be all strings, all double, all ints or a combination of all.

Now, for every column X[] I need to know the datatype. Like:

- If everything is 0 or 1, then Boolean (or binomial)
- elseIf everything is integer, then integer
- elseIf everything is double, then double
- else: String

I need something like this in C#.

Comment: What do you exactly have as input? Strings?

Comment: Show us your code; and where is `X` initialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems what you're trying to do here is find the "lowest common denominator" of types here.  The most derived type that all of the items in the collection "are".

We'll start out with this helper method to get the entire type hierarchy of an object (including itself):

```
public static IEnumerable<Type> BaseClassHierarchy(object obj)
{
    Type current = obj.GetType();
    do
    {
        yield return current;
        current = current.BaseType;
    } while (current != null);
}
```

Now we can take a sequence of objects, map each to its hierarchy, intersect all of those sequences with each other, and then the first item of that result is the most derived type that is common to all of the other objects:

```
public static Type MostDerivedCommonType(IEnumerable<object> objects)
{
    return objects.Select(o => BaseClassHierarchy(o))
        .Aggregate((a,b)=> a.Intersect(b))
        .First();
}
```

Comment: I have to do those checks because I dont know what will the user input. I will try the TryParse function as soon as possible. Thank you all for your prompt answers.

Answer (score 0):

One simple idea is you can try to cast/parse as the different types and if that fails, move on to the next type. A very brief example of this is:

```
foreach (var element in myArray) {
  double parsedDouble; int parsedInt;

  var defaultValue = element.ToString();
  if (Double.TryParse(defaultValue, out parsedDouble)) {
    // you have something that can be used as a double (the value is in "parsedDouble")
  } else if (Int32.TryParse(defaultValue, out parsedInt)){
    // you have something that can be used as an integer (the value is in "parsedInt")
  } else {
    // you have something that can be used as an string (the value is in "defaultValue")
  }
}
```

I believe that should probably get you started. Good luck!

*Note*

As other's have said - it is better to use strong types in C#. In most cases you can probably select a single type and use that rather than performing the checks above.

Comment: My final answer looks much as drew_w suggested, all were very accurate despite my bad way to make the question, thanks.